# Proving $\sqrt{2}(a+b+c) \geq \sqrt{1+a^2} + \sqrt{1+b^2} + \sqrt{1+c^2}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, problem-solving

I've been going through some of my notes when I found the following inequality for $a,b,c>0$ and $abc=1$:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{2}(a+b+c) \geq \sqrt{1+a^2} + \sqrt{1+b^2} + \sqrt{1+c^2}
\end{equation*}
$$

This was what I attempted, but that yielded no result whatsoever:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2}(a+b+c) &\geq \sqrt{1+a^2} + \sqrt{1+b^2} + \sqrt{1+c^2}\\
&\geq \sqrt{abc+a²} + \sqrt{abc+b²} + \sqrt{abc+c²}\\
&\geq \sqrt{a(bc+a)}+\sqrt{b(ac+b)}+\sqrt{c(ab+c)}\\
&\geq \sqrt{a\left(\frac{1}{a}+a\right)}+\sqrt{b\left(\frac{1}{b}+b\right)}+\sqrt{c\left(\frac{1}{c}+c\right)}
\end{align}
$$
With this we then have
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+a²} &= \sqrt{a\left(\frac{1}{a}+a\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{a\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{a²}{a}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{a\left(\frac{1+a²}{a}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{1+a²}
\end{align}
$$
This yields nothing but frustration and gets me back to step 0

Comment: I tried for half an hour and I failed miserably. One simple observation is that you cannot bound them separately by just looking at terms included a, terms included b and term included c. Unfortunately I don't have time now to play with it now, I will try again later and hope something nice works :)

Comment: @CheeHan this bloody thing has been making me sleepless for at least two days! Thanks for trying, I hope someone can slay this beast eventually

Comment: Can you replace the image with a few $\LaTeX$ lines? It is a pity to have a nice question with a rather ugly formatting.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I totally agree, but I'm on my phone right now and it's a pain to write LaTeX in it. As soon as I'm home I'll be editing it (if anyone with editing powers feel like deleting the image and copying the development I wrote in the comments please do so).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Said and done :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint

$$\sqrt{2}x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ln{x},x>0$$
it is easy to prove by derivative.

so
$$\sqrt{2}a-\sqrt{a^2+1}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ln{a}\tag{1}$$
$$\sqrt{2}b-\sqrt{b^2+1}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ln{b}\tag{2}$$
$$\sqrt{2}c-\sqrt{c^2+1}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ln{c}\tag{3}$$
$(1)+(2)+(3)$
$$\sqrt{2}(a+b+c)\ge\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}$$

Comment: Nice +1, but you may need derivatives and jugglery to prove that :(

Comment: True that, clever use of the properties of natural logarithm to get rid of the possibility that log term might be negative!

Comment: I see what you did there, quite clever! One thing though, what's the proof for $\sqrt{2}x-\sqrt{x^2+1} \geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ln{x}$

Answer (score 2):

here is another way which is not use derivative:

first we need to know: $\sqrt{\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}} \ge \dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}{3}$ (1)

to prove it, we have  $\sqrt{\dfrac{x+y}{2}} \ge \dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2} \implies \sqrt{\dfrac{x+y+z+t}{4}} \ge \dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{t}}{4}$
 let $t= \dfrac{x+y+z}{3}$ we have (1)

squre both sides:

$2(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3+(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2\sum {\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2+a^2b^2}} \iff \sum a^2+4\sum ab -3 \ge 2\sum {\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2+a^2b^2}} \iff \sum a^2+2\sum ab -3 \ge 2\sqrt{3(3+2\sum a^2+\sum a^2b^2)} \iff (\sum a^2-3)^2+8(\sum a^2-3)(\sum ab)+16(\sum ab)^2 \ge 36+24\sum a^2+12 \sum a^2b^2 $

note $(\sum ab)^2-\sum a^2b^2=2abc(a+b+c)=2(a+b+c) \iff (\sum a^2-3)^2+8(\sum a^2)(\sum ab-3) +4((\sum ab)^2-6\sum ab+9)+24(a+b+c)-72 \ge 0$

$abc=1$, so it is trivial $a+b+c \ge 3, ab+bc+ac \ge 3$ so the last one is true.

Comment: I'm confused with $\sum a^2+4\sum ab -3 \ge 2\sum {\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2+a^2b^2}} \iff \sum a^2+2\sum ab -3 \ge 2\sqrt{3(3+2\sum a^2+\sum a^2b^2)}$. These two inequalities are not *identical*, so either $\Rightarrow$ or $\Leftarrow$...

Comment: ya, maybe $\Leftarrow$ is better.

Comment: Quite nice +1.  Inequality (1) is of course just QM-AM.